# Msmq what is the right way of implementation of users

Tags: c#, .net, msmq

So, this is not the right title probably, i was not sure how to put it and how to explain in, lets try !

i have a system that manage more then 720,000 users, i did not use queue until now and i want to start using it, lets give an example os a class that hold a user

```
[Serializable]
    public class UserName
    {
        public string UserNameName { get; set; }
        public string TheResonILikeTo { get; set; }
    }
```

so, if i want to put a message inside my queue its simple

```
public static void Createandsendmessageclass()
        {
            //From Windows Service, use this code
            MessageQueue messageQueue = null;
            if (MessageQueue.Exists(@".\Private$\SomeTestName"))
            {
                messageQueue = new MessageQueue(@".\Private$\SomeTestName");
                messageQueue.Label = "Testing Queue";
            }
            else
            {
                // Create the Queue
                MessageQueue.Create(@".\Private$\SomeTestName");
                messageQueue = new MessageQueue(@".\Private$\SomeTestName");
                messageQueue.Label = "Newly Created Queue";
            }
            UserName user = new UserName();
            user.UserNameName = "Alon";
            user.TheResonILikeTo = "Fuc??";
            messageQueue.Send(user);
        }
```

until here all is great and smooth. nothing to worry about.

But, lets say i have 720,000 users that has messages with different name,

- Alon
- Erez
  *Ylan

and so on..

should i put a different queue for each user, or can i ask the system to give me only messages for user "alon" by usernamename?

another question, how can i tell my code to keep getting messages? running in a while loop?

thanks everyone ! good day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most important thing to remember is that MSMQ is a network protocol, not a database. It isn't appropriate for a system designed to store messages for 720,000 users. 
All your data for users should be stored in a database.

Comment: You miss understood me here, i am keeping my users in a database, i am talking about messaging  here, not information.

Comment: "I am talking about messaging here." 
Sure, but where are you sending messages 'from' and 'to'? 

Note that every connecting device has to be running MSMQ.

Comment: I can see a few scenarios:

Scenario 1.
Server-based app sends messages to queue on user's PC. 
App running on PC locally-receives and processes message. 
This creates an outgoing queue on server for EVERY destination PC that requires a message to be delivered.
Outgoing queues are dynamically created and destroyed so there will be between 0-720,000 queues.

Comment: Scenario 2.
Server-based app sends messages to user-specific queue on server. 
App running on PC remotely-receives and processes message. 
This requires a server-based queue for EVERY user (720,000 queues, unless you remove queues that become empty).

Comment: Scenario 3.
There is one queue on server which all users can access.
Server-based app sends messages to queue with some distinguishing feature. 
App running on PC remotely-receives and processes messages that contain distinguishing feature that matches user. 
Downside - no privacy.

Comment: All of these will fail at the scale you are looking at.
Any MSMQ server will run of out resources and die.

Comment: Let me tell you the scenario and you can try to help me out here. when a user does X, the server is putting something in the queue with the userid of X. There is an app sitting on his computer which check a restfull api every 5 seconds, asking the server. do you have anything for me? how can i check if there is something.. ? for this spesipic  ID. thanksl

Comment: That's scenario 2, no?

Comment: now the real question is.. will a server handle it? or is it just smart to not use queue and keep with the sql.. when a user come it go to sql and take all the information from there.. is that what should i do ? or do 720,000 queues.. not sure.

Comment: Please, for the sake of the server, don't try and use queues :-) http://blogs.msdn.com/b/johnbreakwell/archive/2007/02/15/so-what-s-the-limit-on-connections-to-an-msmq-server.aspx

Comment: Item #4 http://blogs.msdn.com/b/johnbreakwell/archive/2006/09/18/insufficient-resources-run-away-run-away.aspx